# Accomplished autodidact theoretical computer scientists

Tags: soft-question

While it is very common to see successful autodidact musicians, painters, authors and architects - I am not familiar with any famous autodidacts in the field of TCS.
Are there any examples of an accomplished autodidact theoretical computer scientist (i.e., someone who published a significant paper, without ever going to grad school) ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Jeff Edmonds doesn't have a Ph.D

Comment: Two huge names in theory B (both Turing award winners) - Robin Milner http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Milner and Tony Hoare http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare

Comment: @Suresh: Jeff Edmonds' CV says that he does: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/%7Ejeff/cv.pdf (Assuming that's the Jeff Edmonds you mean)

Comment: I don't see the point of the question.

Comment: I think Suresh probably meant Jack Edmonds. Bob Floyd also had no Ph.D.

Comment: Do you count people like Jacob Fox, Daniel Kane, and Mihai Patrascu, who published significant results years before they went to graduate school?

Comment: arggh. sorry that's what I meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to some of the great people listed in the comments, [Gregory Chaitin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_Chaitin) independently developed much of Kolmogorov complexity while he was a highschool student in New York city.